# Flask wtf form render errors in html

Tags: python, html, flask-wtforms

I have a flask form and I added some custom errors but they are not showing up in the browser when I run the page. None of the errors are being listed[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsmJn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJkyK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnm5i.png)

I am expecting to see an error being listed but no errors are being listed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with your html. You're using `<li>` elements for the outside of your list when you should either be using `<ol>` (ordered lists) or `<ul>` (unordered lists) for the outer bracket to wrap the `<li>` elements. Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: I don't quite understand it

Comment: Oh okay I get it now. Thanks. You were so helpful. It was indeed about the lists